# Database column names in API result

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

I'm attempting to design a small API for our product. We have a MySQL database and I'm using a small framework for creating simple GET/POST commands in PHP.

The problem that I am having is that I am not sure how to expose the data from the database without revealing the column names from the tables. For example, at the moment, when someone makes a GET request to an endpoint, I do something like this to return some JSON data:

```
 $rs = mysql_query($sql);
 if($rs) $rsc = mysql_num_rows($rs);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $data[] = $row;
 }

header("HTTP/1.1 202 OK");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

(Yes, I know that mysql_* is bad bad bad. =) Nearly 15 year old code base. Going to be a fun time converting over...)

This way of doing things is nice and simple, but it also puts the column names from the database out there in plain site (which we've always made an effort to never reveal). An example of what would be returned is:

```
[{"NewsID":"559110","Day":"10\/17\/13","UnixDT":"1382031900","Subject":"Testing formatting"},{"NewsID":"535214","Day":"09\/10\/13","UnixDT":"1378836900","Subject":"Check Template - use tempate from tempate mgr"},
```

Is this frame of mind just something I need to get used to with a public-facing API or is there a better way to return data that doesn't use column names as the key name. We've never built a semi-public facing API before, so any points or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I think what I'm struggling with is whether or not I need to try and "mask" my column names by creating alias as you suggested or if I should just use the column names themselves. It's more of a philosophy question than a logistical one. Sorry if that wasn't super clear.

Comment: I'm currently working on an API myself. I've named all the columns so they're developer friendly. As long as you build your system securely I don't see a problem with the column names coming out. If you have an SQL injection point then you might have a problem.

Comment: I agree with @diggersworld as long as your system is secure and your column names are readable there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `array_combine` or you will need to update your SQL using `AS`

```
$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c', ...);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $data[] = array_combine($keys, array_values($row));
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks so much for the suggestion. I posted in a comment on the question that what I'm really struggling with is whether or not I need to "mask" the column names of my database tables.